# Correlation EMF / DNA

Tags: rf, damage

What is the current state of independent (of producers) studies about the correlation between EMF (with particular reference to mobile devices) and interruption of human DNA? Are the declared SAR by devices manufacturers reliable?

Comment: First off, your going to have a really really tough sell on any paper that suggests EM waves affect DNA because EM waves attenuate as soon as they hit a solid object and second, the activation energy for DNA to change chemically is going to be much much higher than what an EM from consumer devices can deliver. Thirdly, this is a site about circuit theory not speculation, this question is off topic. There is one type of EM wave that can affect DNA, it's called ultraviolet light.

Comment: Magnetic fields do penetrate the skull; its been shown the calcium ion channels are "upset" by 60Hz fields.

Comment: @lapt Among the rare independent studies there was that of Professor Henry Lay from Seattle University, who conducted experiments with electromagnetic waves on laboratory mice. Demonstrating that the rats exposed for only two hours to cell radiation showed broken DNA. Only two years later Professor Jerry Phillips came to the same conclusions regarding human DNA. Among the diseases produced by the interruption of DNA there would also be different types of cancer. And according to Gabanelli (a tv journalist), Motorola would try to hide this research in order to silence the echo in public opinion

Comment: Finally, why would I be OT? Isn't this belonging to circuits theory, their effects on external environment..?

Comment: Yep, DNA gets broken all the time in cells. You need a *mechanism* (or a reason cell radiation will break DNA) cell phone radiation does not have enough energy to do this. Come back when you have a mechanism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best papers I have seen on the subject are this:

[image]
Source: https://xkcd.com/radiation/

And if you look closely at the chart you'll see this:
[image]

If your are really concerned about radiation, you should stop eating banannas, not be concerned about cell phones.

Your body also generates antimatter:

> When Potassium-40 decays, it releases a positron, the electron’s
>   antimatter twin, so you also contain a small amount of antimatter. The
>   average human produces more than 4000 positrons per day, about 180 per
>   hour. But it’s not long before these positrons bump into your
>   electrons and annihilate into radiation in the form of gamma rays.
>   Source: https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/article/the-particle-physics-of-you

So why doesn't everyone get cancer? Because your body can stop cancer in dozens of ways and repair DNA.

The next one is this:

[image]
Source: https://xkcd.com/925/

If cell phones did really cause cancer in humans, then you would have seen the cancer rate go up substantially. The last thing is, people are wierd when it comes to cancer, because they don't understand how it works and they hate the unknown.

These two charts show *conclusively* that cellphones do not cause cancer.

EDIT

Just to re-iterate the cancer chart, if you look at the CDC brain cancer rates have not gone up since the advent of cell phones. I would expect that if cell phones did cause brain cancer, the rate would have gone up mirrored with the rate of cell phone usage.

[image]
Source: https://www.cdc.gov/cancer/dcpc/research/articles/cancer_2020_figures.htm

Comment: The XKCD radiation chart is referring to nuclear radiation, not electromagnetic radiation. It isn't particularly relevant here, and it certainly doesn't show anything "conclusively".

Comment: You didn't see the box for cell phone radiation then

Comment: Edited for the cell phone part

Comment: No, I'm quite aware of that part. The fact remains that the _only_ thing that implies is that cell phones don't emit radioactivity. This doesn't mean that electromagnetic radiation is harmless -- the emissions from a laser cutter are purely electromagnetic as well, but that doesn't mean you should stick your hand in it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that low levels of 1.7-2.4GHz are harmless, otherwise with the advent of cellphones the cancer rate would have gone up, as shown in the last graph

Comment: @laptop2d I agree with duskw, in fact I thought the same things: radioactivity isn't' in the object of the topic; EM activity is the source of discord. If I measure my device with a Geiger I do detect nothing, but with a EMF detector I measure a lot of mG. The null correlation may reveal that the time of exposition is not sufficient for medical statistics. Moreover, the studies I've cited are something real, and others have been made in the years..otherwise, why  important organizations for public health monitoring would have fixed precise limits for devices SAR (1.6 and 2 W/kg in US and UE)?

Comment: I read online some thread where users complain that the declared values distance themselves from measurings they did using the app Quanta Monitor. I have their same device, but I didn't do the measure for security reasons because the app is not available on the play store anymore.

Comment: Did you look at the lower graph? No cancer from cellphones, what then are you worried about? Where does it say that the SAR limits are to avoid damage to DNA? I couldn't find any information anywhere

Comment: @laptop2d 1) I had seen it, and I said that null correlation may reveal etc. 2) On the website of the Federal Communications Commission (FCC), the US federal organization that monitors the effects of mobile phones on health, it is reported that "working closely with the federal agencies for health and safety, including the Food and Drug Administration (FDA), the FCC has adopted limits for safe exposure to radio frequency energy. These limits are provided using a unit of measurement called the Specific Absorption Rate (SAR), which calculates the amount of radio-frequency energy absorbed by...

Comment: ...the body using the mobile phone. The FCC therefore requires mobile phone manufacturers to ensure that their mobile phones do not exceed the limits beyond which radiation is unsafe. Any device that does not exceed this threshold (ie, all those sold legally in the US) is therefore safe. Source: http://www.ilsussidiario.net/mobile/Cronaca/2011/11/28/RADIAZIONI-CELLULARI-Ecco-come-calcolare-le-onde-emesse-dal-vostro-telefonino/225213/AMP/

Comment: See also https://www-ilsecoloxix-it.cdn.ampproject.org/v/www.ilsecoloxix.it/Facet/amp/Uuid/3f934078-19af-11e1-b2e9-7bd1d093cf6d/Cellulari_dannosi_Report_mette_in_allerta_lItalia_FABcellulari.xml?amp_js_v=a2&amp_gsa=1&usqp=mq331AQCCAE%3D#referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&amp_tf=Da%20%251%24s&ampshare=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ilsecoloxix.it%2Fp%2Fmagazine%2F2011%2F11%2F28%2FAOu9qXRB-cellulari_dannosi_allerta.shtml (it is notorious that media information contains a lot of fake news, but I think this time is not the case)